# Modelsim break on one gen instance

Tags: debugging, verilog, modelsim

I have a module which is being replicated inside a gen block. To debug the replicated module I insert a breakpoint on one of the statements. However Modelsim breaks on the same statement for all of the instances in the gen block. How can I make modelsim break only once for a certain gen block and not for all of them?

To be specific I picked a particular generate instance from the sim window to place my breakpoint, but the simulator still breaks at all the generate instances.

I am using Modelsim Altera Student Edition on CentOS 6.7

Comment: It would be help full to post code or a simplified version indicating which line shows the break point.

Comment: You could uses a parameter which is set 1 when loop variable is 5. and use parameter to enable some function in the module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Goto Tool->Breakpoints. Select the breakpoint you just added and hit "modify".
There is an instance name field that you can fill in to the generated instance name.